# Prometheus tsdb retention time

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

[image]The prometheus retention configuration is below:

```
 --storage.tsdb.retention.size=200GB \
 --storage.tsdb.retention.time=30d  \
```

With the above configuration keep data in prometheus for 10 days. Suddenly we got data for the last two days.

**The below is from Prometheus documentation:**
If both time and size retention policies are specified, whichever triggers first will be used.

Expired block cleanup happens in the background. It may take up to two hours to remove expired blocks. Blocks must be fully passed before they are released.

I could not find something relevant in the documentation of prometheus, maybe I miss something. Could you please explain why we got data for the last 2 days?

Thank you

Comment: Just to get this out of the way: did you storage 'ate' 200GB in two days?

Comment: I do not know what happened pls refer to the picture above

Comment: I mean could it be that you added some particularly heavy targets, which resulted in your prometheus exceeding 200GB in two days, and cleaning was triggered by size retention policy?

Comment: We did not. If 200GB is exceeded then Prometheus cleans the whole database?

Today we had the same issue and have data from past two days.

Comment: No, it cleans a couple of blocks, so that its storage is within policy. But if you have anomalies in size of scraped data, it can result in cleaning of almost all (but defenetly not all!) data.